# How do I get the value when using useState outside of the function?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to take this form in the code and make it so I can put it in data so I can post it to my database.

Is there a way to take the value of the steps useState and set it to a state?

Here is the specific function with the useState

```
const StepInput = () => {
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState([{ value: null }]);

  function handleChange(i, event) {
    const values = [...steps];
    values[i].value = event.target.value;
    setSteps(values);
  }

  function handleAdd() {
    const values = [...steps];
    values.push({ value: null });
    setSteps(values);
  }

  function handleRemove(i) {
    const values = [...steps];
    values.splice(i, 1);
    setSteps(values);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleAdd()}>
        +
      </button>

      {steps.map((step, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={`${step}-${idx}`}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Step"
              value={step.value || ""}
              onChange={e => handleChange(idx, e)}
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={() => handleRemove(idx)}>
              X
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
)
}
```

And here is where it is called. This is where I will be posting the data using Axios.

```
export default class RecipeCreationForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
          recipe_name: "",
          recipe_difficulty: "",
      }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      errorText: ""
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
      console.log(this.value.props.step)
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <form>
                  <input 
                    className="input-box"
                    type="text"
                    name="recipe_name"
                    placeholder="Recipe Name"
                    value={this.state.recipe_name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <input 
                    className="input-box"
                    type="text"
                    name="recipe_difficulty"
                    placeholder="Recipe difficulty 1-10"
                    value={this.state.recipe_difficulty}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <StepInput />
                  <button type="submit">Create Recipe</button>
              </form>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't mix hooks with class base component, pick one but not both. as the question you shouldn't replicate one state to another, that's bad practice. keep one single source of truth, use `steps` as props at your form.

Comment: What would you suggest I do? Im using state for the rest of the form but I need to be able to add as many steps as possible. I cannot seem to think up a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend there is a lot of ways.

The most simple and recommended for the case is just pass a callback function for your
step input.

```
// at RecipeCreationForm 
simpleCallback= (stepInpuData) =>{
// your code here
}

<StepInput simpleCallback={simpleCallback}


// on your step input file

const StepInput = ({simpleCallback}) =>{

  useEffect(() => {
    simpleCallback(steps)
  }, [steps])
```

for more complex cases you have redux.

but you can use Apollo too (Redux is far too much complex)

Comment: When doing this I get an error saying simpleCallback is not defined. Also, is this all in the StepInput.js file or is some in one and some in the other?

Comment: I just edited the answer to match your question :)